# My code suddently stops in the middle of the loop

Tags: python, loops

When I execute it, the output ONLY WITH BIG NUMBERS is like:

annualInterestRate = 0.2
Remaining balance month  1  is  5073.33
Remaining balance month  2  is  5147.89
Remaining balance month  3  is  5223.69
Remaining balance month  4  is  5300.75
Remaining balance month  5  is  5379.1

It stops in month 5 instead of month 12
I don't know why with a lower balance, for example 50, it does execute the whole code. Here i attach it.

```
balance0 = float(input("balance = " ))
annualInterestRate = float(input("annualInterestRate = " ))
monthlyPayment = 10
balance = 0


month = 1
while (1):
 balance = balance0
 while month <= 12:
    balance1= round((balance + annualInterestRate * balance/12), 2)

    balance1 = balance1 - (monthlyPayment)
    print("Remaining balance month " , month, " is ", balance1)
    balance = balance1
    month += 1
 if balance < 0:
       print("Lowest payment: ", monthlyPayment)
       break

 else: 
     monthlyPayment += 10
```

Comment: did you step through your code through a couple of iterations to see if the basic calculations work?

Comment: yeah it does, if i make balance = 50 instead a bigger number it does

Answer (score 0):

```
>> balance = 5000
>> annualInterestRate = 0.2
('Remaining balance month ', 1, ' is ', 5073.33)
('Remaining balance month ', 2, ' is ', 5147.89)
('Remaining balance month ', 3, ' is ', 5223.69)
('Remaining balance month ', 4, ' is ', 5300.75)
('Remaining balance month ', 5, ' is ', 5379.1)
('Remaining balance month ', 6, ' is ', 5458.75)
('Remaining balance month ', 7, ' is ', 5539.73)
('Remaining balance month ', 8, ' is ', 5622.06)
('Remaining balance month ', 9, ' is ', 5705.76)
('Remaining balance month ', 10, ' is ', 5790.86)
('Remaining balance month ', 11, ' is ', 5877.37)
('Remaining balance month ', 12, ' is ', 5965.33)
```

Seems to work on my machine.
Running python 2.7/12 mac osx sierra

However, It doesn't ever finish thanks to the `while(1)`. That can be removed and the script will run the same.

Comment: It doesn't leave the loop for me if I put a large balance in. Looks like the balance never goes below 0 for large numbers, so the outer loop never exits.

Comment: Also works for me, but it ends up with an infinite loop because there is no `break` in the `else` branch

Answer (score 0):

With your code exactly, for an example like `balance=50` & `annualinterestrate=0.2`, I get negative numbers when it runs past month `5`.
Samething, but with `balance=20` & `annualinterestrate=0.2`, I get negative numbers when it runs past month `2`. There is a correlation between numbers < 100.

However, with each test, your code never broke or threw any errors and the math is sound.